# Enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp sin abrir la aplicación

Tags: android, whatsapp, mensajes

Tengo el siguiente método para enviar un mensaje por WhatsApp desde la aplicación que estoy desarrollando.

```
public void enviarWhatsApp(String telefono, String mensaje){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+telefono+"&text="+mensaje));
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando le doy al botón que cree para enviar el mensaje, me abre esta pantalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es enviarlo directamente sin que me tenga que abrir la conversación.

Answer (score 2):

**Enviar un mensaje sin necesidad de abrir la aplicación no puede ser posible usando la API, el principal motivo es la seguridad.**

Por lo pronto ùnicamente puedes enviar un mensaje a un télefono determinado usando un `Intent` :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hola Abisur Diaz.");
 try{
     startActivity(intent);
 }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La aplicación Whastapp no se encuentra instalada en el dispositivo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```